# How to create alternative versions of an image for different display/device scenarios(Art direction) with NextJS Image component?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, responsive-design

I want to create responsive images in my NextJS project. To achieve that, MDN documentation suggest to use **picture** element with **source** [responsive-images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) . For example:

```js
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg" />
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg" />
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva" />
</picture>
```

But my problem is I could not find any usage in NextJS. Can I use picture and source element with **NextJS Image component**? If yes how can I achieve that ?